# How to process insane date inputs with php

Tags: php, date

I have a code in php for processing the personal details of a person. I need code to handle the date input such that when the user inputs a year like ***1900*** and below then the program outputs ***That is impossible***. I have successfully handled how the program should respond if the date input is in the ***future***.
The program takes date input from the user in the ***European Date Format*** for example ***21-10-1990***, Am having a hard time processing this because the php in-built function ***time()*** returns a unix timestamp measured since ***January 1st 1970***. Is there a way I can circumvent this to achieve detection of years startimg from 1900 and below without applying a conditional structure to the year directly?

***Code***

```
<?php 

class User{
    //initialize the user properties
    public string $name="";
    public string $dob="";
    public string $national_id="";
    public string $tel="";
    public string $email="";
    public function User($user_name,$dob,$national_id,$tel,$mail){
        //assign the values inside the constructor
        $this->name=$user_name;
        $this->dob=$dob;
        $this->national_id=$national_id;
        $this->tel=$tel;
        $this->email=$mail;
    }
    function validate_dob(){
    
    
        //get a new time in millis from the date passed in
        
        $date_obj=strtotime($this->dob);
        //add conditional structures to make sure the date is not in the 
        //future and is within acceptable time range
        //get the current time from the unix timestamp
        $current_time=time();
        if($date_obj>$current_time){
            echo "\n";
            echo "That is impossible, you birth date cannot be in the future";
        }
        //if the date is also 1900 and below then also throw an error, i need help here

    }
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend using PHP's `DateTime` class, https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php, instead of `time()` and `strtotime()`

Comment: It works for handling the future birth date, I just want to make it work for insane date times like 1900, 1899 and so on and so forth, am open to suggestions via answers with the said classes

Comment: Make use of [IntlCalendar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlcalendar.php).

Comment: If you handle future dates with `>`, you can handle past dates with `<`. Unix time for 1900-01-01 midnight UTC is `-2208988800`. I'm a bit confused about the exact question being asked here since you mention lots of different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead of `time()` and `strtotime()`

```php
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y',$this->dob);
$current_time = new DateTime('NOW');
$date1900 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y','01-01-1900');

if($date_obj > $current_time){
    echo "\n";
    echo "That is impossible, your birth date cannot be in the future";
}else
if($date_obj < $date1900){
    echo "\n";
    echo "That is impossible, your birth date cannot before the year 1900";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime()

```
$date1   =   date('d-m-Y',strtotime($this->dob));
$date2   =   date('d-m-Y',strtotime(time());

$d1 = new DateTime($date1);
$d2 = new DateTime($date2); 
if($date1 >$date2 ){
     echo "\n";
   echo "That is impossible, you birth date cannot be in the future";
}
```